# How to lower the minimum brightness?

Tags: root-access, 8.0-oreo, motorola, screen-brightness

On my Moto Z Play on the stock 8.0 Oreo ROM (rooted, of course), I find that the lowest brightness setting is still a bit too bright for my liking. This is in contrast with my dad's Galaxy S8+ which goes so dark. One solution that I liked was GravityBox. Unfortunately, that requires Xposed and Xposed breaks Messenger at the moment, and I can't live with the Lite version of Messenger. Xposed also isn't actively developed nowadays so the issue won't be fixed anytime soon.

I'm looking for something that will achieve what GravityBox does, that is, lower the minimum brightness value for my ROM. I don't want any screen filter app that runs in the background all day, that just sucks. It isn't as effective as actually dimming the display, IMO.

Can you guys help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this by hand you can (with a root terminal):

### 1. Disable auto brightness

```
settings put system screen_brightness_mode 0
```

### 2. Set desired brightness

```
settings put system screen_brightness 1
```

Where the value must be between 1 and 255 (inclusive)

Answer (score 0):

Since your device is running on Android 8.0 Oreo, you can follow the instructions below to change the minimum brightness level on your device.

1. Download the Brightness Tweak from [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/devdb/project/dl/?id=17614).
2. Go to Settings and allow installation from Unknown Sources.
3. Open the app and grant the SU permission.
4. On the next screen follow the on-screen instructions and complete the initial setup.
5. Once done, you will be greeted with a screen where you can set the minimum brightness level for your device. The minimum brightness level that you can go to is 1.